# How to add the peak labels to an FTIR spectrum?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have tried to plot the next FTIR spectrum and add their respective peak labels using `Graphics` and `Show`, but I think this doesn't work with `ScalingFunctions`, because the peak labels don't appear. Do you know any other way to do it?

```
ir = Import[
   "C:/Users/gafla/Documents/FQ Avanzada/dfrx_2.xlsx", {"Data", 1, 
    Range[2, 935], {8, 9}}];
ir1 = Rotate[
   Style[Text["1500.6 \[LongRightArrow]", {1500.618848, 95.9 - .3}], 
    12, Bold], 90 Degree];
ir2 = Rotate[
   Style[Text["1348.9 \[LongRightArrow]", {1348.889888, 96.4 - .3}], 
    12, Bold], 90 Degree];
ir3 = Rotate[
   Style[Text["1045.4 \[LongRightArrow]", {1045.418272, 97.0 - .3}], 
    12, Bold], 90 Degree];
ir4 = Rotate[
   Style[Text["956.7 \[LongRightArrow]", {956.692736, 96.3 - .3}], 12,
     Bold], 90 Degree];
ir5 = Rotate[
   Style[Text["833.2 \[LongRightArrow]", {833.248512, 96.0 - .3}], 12,
     Bold], 90 Degree];
ir6 = Rotate[
   Style[Text["705.9 \[LongRightArrow]", {705.946656, 96.6 - .3}], 12,
     Bold], 90 Degree];
ir7 = Rotate[
   Style[Text["459.0 \[LongRightArrow]", {459.058208, 96.4 - .3}], 12,
     Bold], 90 Degree];

txtir = Graphics[{ir1, ir2, ir3, ir4, ir5, ir6, ir7}];

pir = ListLinePlot[{ir}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Range[400, 4000, 400], None}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Transmitancia (%)", 
      None}, {"Número de onda (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \
\(-1\)]\))", None}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> {{300, 4100}, {94, 101}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   Axes -> False];

Show[pir, txtir]
```

[image]

[dfrx_2.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SP3NADw9w6qLque4pNGdr1sn_vX-sdpt/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more convenient approach is to use `Labeled` on selected points:

First a function that labels a point `p` with its rounded rotated first coordinate:

```
toLabeled[p_] := Labeled[p, 
   Rotate[Style[Row[{Round[p[[1]], .1], "⟶    "}],  12, Bold], 90 Degree], 
   Below]
```

Points from `ir` to be labeled (here these points are extracted from your `ir1` ... `ir7`):

```
nF = Nearest[ir[[All, 1]] -> Automatic];
selectedpoints = {ir1, ir2, ir3, ir4, ir5, ir6, ir7} /. 
    Rotate[Style[Text[_, pos_], ___], ___] :> ir[[First[nF @ pos[[1]]]]];
```

A replacement rule that replaces a point `p` in `selectedpoints` to `toLabeled[p]`

```
labelrule = pt : Alternatives @@ selectedpoints :> toLabeled[pt];
```

Use `labelerule` with `ReplaceAll` to create a modified version of `ir`:

```
irnew = ir /. labelrule;

ListLinePlot[irnew, Frame -> True,  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Range[400, 4000, 400], None}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Transmitancia (%)", None}, 
    {"Número de onda (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-1\)]\))", None}},
  PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{300, 4100}, {94, 101}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Axes -> False]
```

[image]